# How to get the selected value of a selectbox and pass it to an action?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I need to pass the value of the selectbox to it's widget's handler function

```
var payment = CardService.newSelectionInput()
  .setType(CardService.SelectionInputType.DROPDOWN)
  .setTitle("payment mode")
  .setFieldName("payment_mode")
  .addItem("Debit card", "contact", false)
  .addItem("Net banking", "lead", true)
  .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("onModeChange"));
section.addWidget(payment);
```

I expect something like `setFunctionName("onModeChange").setParams(payment.value)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your script is almost the correct. You can achieve what you want by modifying a little. In your case, you want to retrieve `contact` or `lead` at the function `onModeChange`. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

In your script, you can retrieve the selected values as follows. When an user selects, the selected values are sent to `onModeChange`, immediately. Please add this function in your script.

```
function onModeChange(e) {
    console.log(e.formInput.payment_mode)
}
```

If the user selects `Debit card` and `Net banking`, you can retrieve `contact` and `lead` at `e.formInput.payment_mode`, respectively.

If you want to give the additional values when the user selects, please modify

From

```
.setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("onModeChange"))
```

To :

```
.setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("onModeChange").setParameters({key1: "value1"}))
```

By this modification, at `onModeChange(e)`, you can retrieve the added values by `e.parameters.key1`.

#### Note :

- This sample supposes that both your script works and you can see the select box at the gmail addon. If your script didn't work yet, please tell me.

#### References :

- [setFunctionName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action#setfunctionnamefunctionname)
- [setParameters()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/action#setparametersparameters)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Works like a charm. I wonder why the documentation does not explain these tiny things.

Comment: @Hari Balaji I think so. When I had used this, I had not been able to find such documents. So I checked the object using ``Logger.log(e)`` and ``console.log(e)``. I would like to think to summarize and publish such information if it is useful for users.

Comment: Can you look into this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460875/authorising-non-google-services-in-a-gmail-add-on ?

Comment: @Hari Balaji I saw it just now. But I couldn't understand what you want to do. I'm sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: I basically was trying to have a login form in my app. But , we dont have <input type='password'> here. So I was trying to implement this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47904710/password-type-field-in-gmail-card-service. I am stuck here. What is 'usercallback'  referred to in that answer. Is that a keyword or is it referring to a method ? Can you pls help me with this ?

Comment: @Hari Balaji I'm really sorry I couldn't understand about it.

Comment: @Hari Balaji I'm sorry I couldn't help.